# What is the largest pub/bar in Europe?

Tags: europe, food-and-drink, where-on-earth, factoids

What is Europe's largest pub or bar? Please do not include places which are basically just breweries.

I thought it was "World's End" in London but after visiting other places I am no longer sure.

Comment: English style pub and similar places https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub Bier stubes are fine for the indoor part only. No breweries.

Comment: [Largest pub in the world opened in Australia](http://metro.co.uk/2011/06/21/biggest-pub-in-the-world-eatons-hill-hotel-opens-in-brisbane-australia-52470/) with a total capacity of **7000** customers. :O

Comment: Surely one of the Oktoberfest tents would qualify?

Comment: I find this question very strange because I feel moderate size is an inherent feature of an "English style pub".

Comment: I think the title/contents of this question should be changed from 'pub' to 'place to drink for money'.

Comment: I always thought Düsseldorf's Kö is the largest pub. But it is partly ourdoors.

Answer (score 7):

[The Moon Under Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Under_Water,_Manchester) in Manchester, UK [is said to hold the Guinness World Record for being the biggest pub in Britain](https://www.drinkadvisor.com/en/bars/manchester/12542-moon-under-water.html). Wikipedia quotes a surface of 8800 square feet, and a capacity of 1700 customers. Some claim it is also the biggest in Europe although this lacks an official confirmation.

[The community on Answers.com has a different opinion.](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_biggest_pub_in_Europe) According to them, the biggest pub in Europe is the  Drie Gezusters in Groningen, Holland. This claim too lacks an official source. However some data on its size and capacity is available on [its Dutch Wikipedia page](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drie_Gezusters_%28bedrijf%29), quoting a capacity of 3750 customers for a total of 20 bars. These numbers make it bigger than The Moon Under Water.

[This review on Ciao says the same about the The Regal in Cambridge](http://travel.ciao.co.uk/The_Regal__Review_5311681), UK, although its quoted maximum capacity of 1300 customers places it below The Moon Under Water in the list. [Another capacity estimate for The Regal is 1600 customers](http://metro.co.uk/2011/06/21/biggest-pub-in-the-world-eatons-hill-hotel-opens-in-brisbane-australia-52470/) which still doesn't let it top the list.

Comment: According to https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drie_Gezusters_(bedrijf) , De Drie Gezusters has a capacity of 3750. It has 20 bars. I'm sceptical of such numbers in general though.

Comment: I'd never imagined from the frontage that the Moon Under Water was so big (never bothered going in)

Answer (score 3):

Also consider [Hofbräuhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofbr%C3%A4uhaus_am_Platzl) at Munich, which is awfully huge with around 4000 customers capacity and also very historically important and visible.